# Network port error while installing Filemaker Server

Tags: apache, server, filemaker

I am relatively new to Filemaker Server. I just downloaded the demo to test it out and I got an error saying

> To install Filemaker Server, ports 80 and 443 must be available.

I currently have an apache web server running on the machine and I know I am using these ports so I am not surprised by the error.

What is the best way to go install FMS with a pre-existing apache server running?

Is there a way to change the ports Apache uses? Or should I go about this in a different way? Any help would be great!

P.S. I am on a late 2012 mac mini with OS X Yosemite running Server

Comment: not really a programming question, so this is off-topic here. try super user

Answer (score 1):

Running another apache server on OS X is not supported with FM Server. It is best practice to dedicate a machine to running FM Server and any additional apache hosting run on a different server. You must turn off any running web server, either from server.app or built in web sharing, before installing and deploying FM Server.

Open ports are needed for serving custom web publishing and Web Direct.